# Why am I using x->y = z instead of x.y = z in my C code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, abstract-data-type

I'm following instructions to create code for a flexible array, and I am told to use 
x->y = z instead of x.y = z. What would be the reason to use pointers instead of just assigning values normally?

This code includes a custom library flexarray.h which I'll put at the bottom

flexarray.c:

```
struct flexarrayrec{
   int capacity;
   int itemcount;
   int *items;
};

flexarray flexarray_new(){
   flexarray result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
   result->capacity = 2;
   result->itemcount = 0;
   result->items = emalloc(result->capacity * sizeof result->items[0]);
   return result;
}
```

flexarray.h:

```
#ifndef FLEXARRAY_H_
#define FLEXARRAY_H_

typedef struct flexarrayrec *flexarray;

extern void flexarray_append(flexarray f, int item);
extern void flexarray_free(flexarray f);
extern flexarray flexarray_new();
extern void flexarray_print(flexarray f);
extern void flexarray_sort(flexarray f);

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x->y` is just syntax sugar for this

```
(*x).y
```

Looks like `flexarray` is just typedef for `*flexarrayrec`, so when you write `flexarray result`, compiler will "transform" it to

```
flexarrayrec *result = emalloc(sizeof(flexarrayrec));
```

So `result.capacity`, for example, would have no meaning as pointer is just a number (memory address), "it doesn't have any field". `(*result).capacity` will work, but it's frustrating to write so many asterisks and parentheses, that's why we use `->` operator :)

Answer (score 1):

`x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y` (it is syntactic sugar)

That is, if x is a pointer.
If your structure (or object) is not a pointer, you can use x.y (and not x->y)

In your case you must use dynamic allocation (pointers), since you want to use flexarray outside of the function flexarray_new().

Answer (score 0):

Your `flexarray` is a pointer of `struct flexarrayrec` type. So-

```
typedef struct flexarrayrec *flexarray;
```

When you have structure pointer's you have to use `->` arrow operator to access structure members!

But if you have declared

```
 typedef struct flexarrayrec flexarray; // Static declaration
```

Now you are allowed to use `.` dot operator to access its members!

If you want to use `.` means you can follow-

```
(*x).y = z instead of x->y = z;
```